# Adding elements in loop to container (lifetime)

Tags: c++, scope, local

If I add elements to a vector using the code below, then at the time I call foo, the elements (automatic variables) of vec have been destroyed since the scope in which they are created ends.

```
std::vector<A> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  A a;
  vec.push_back(a);
}

foo(vec);
```

My question is now what the textbook solution to such a problem is

Comment: Its a bit naughty to edit the question when you have answers that refer to what your original code was

Comment: Yes I am sorry, but the problem gets clearer with the push_back function

Comment: The first comment on this question could be a reason - your edit completely changed the meaning of the question which wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the elements in `vec` will be different copies of `a`.

However, you need to allocate the size of `vec` if you want to use `operator[]` or else use `vec.push_back()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) vec.push_back(A());
```

EDIT (after question change):

Even though `push_back()` takes its argument as a reference, internally it will make a copy of it. It takes it argument by reference to avoid making an unnecessary copy prior to making the copy to store internally.

Comment: why? they are passed by reference

Comment: No, the assignment makes a copy of `a`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but i changed the example to vec.push_back(a);

Comment: `push_back()` takes its argument as a reference, but internally it will make a copy of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about stack variables. When you push value in std::vector, this container creates heap copy of the variable. Thus, all your variables will exists, when you're live the scope.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your variable as global and in your loop  just let the value in that variable and then push back